# foreach for a multidemensional array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to loop a multidimensional array, and not quite sure how this is done.

```
$array = array(array('product1'=>'url1'));
$array[] = array('product2'=>'url2');
$array[] = array('product3'=>'url3');

foreach($array as $name=>$url)
{
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$name.'</a>';
}
```

This returns, 
Notice:  Array to string conversion in test.php on line 15

0

Notice:  Array to string conversion in test.php on line 15

1

Notice:  Array to string conversion in test.php on line 15

2

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah? `$_SESSION['products']` is not the array you're looking for?!

Comment: Yah, are you really sure you want to get the session? or the array?

Comment: @source:-hey source you got the answer or still searching for right answer

Comment: oops, I made the $array variable as an example, but used the actual foreach loop I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Please dont use $array as variable name.. much better if it is something like this.

```
$products = array(
  array('product1' => 'url1'),
  array('product2' => 'url2'),
  array('product3' => 'url3')
);
```

Pulling the data:

```
foreach($products as $ind){

  ....

  foreach($ind as $name){
  ....

  }
}
```

Comment: so I do a foreach, within the foreach?

Comment: @Source, yes because it is a multidimensional array. Array in an array

Answer (score 0):

currentpage.php

```
//this is required array which you want to enter in session  
$array = array(
      "product1" => "url1",
      "product2" => "url2",
      "product3" => "url3"
   );

session_start();//here we start a session 
$_SESSION['product_url']=$array;//here we pass required array to session

//By the help of below code we check is session contain array
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($_SESSION);
```

requiedpage.php

```
session_start();//here we start a session
//finally display required data to reqired page... 
foreach($_SESSION['product_url'] as $key=>$value)
{
    echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</a><br>';
}
```

for multidimensional array:-

```
currentpage.php
    //this is required multidimensional array which you want to enter in session  
        $array= array(
                "[0]"=>array("product1" => 'url1',"product2" => 'url2',"product3" => 'url3')
            );
requieredpage.php
        foreach($_SESSION['product_url'] as $key=>$value)
        {
            foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                echo '<a href="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</a><br>';
            }    
        }
```

output i got:-

```
product1
product2
product3
```

Comment: @source:-my friend i try to solve your problem i hope this will help you.i tried which i understand from your code.